# What does mean |sin(z)|<=1?

Tags: complex, trigonometry

I already know that the magnitude of sin(z) its equal to sqrt(sin^2(x)+sinh^2(y))

Answer (score 1):

You're at the wrong site.  Anyway

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x + I y]] == 1, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The max values for `y` are:

```
Solve[Cosh[2 y] == 3, y] /. C[1] -> 0

(* {{y -> -(ArcCosh[3]/2)}, {y -> ArcCosh[3]/2}} *)
```